# Дёргаются и меняют размер элементы при использовании анимации

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

На [сайте](http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/abc/chatlas/) для появления блоков используется анимация (animate.css и wow.js).
На iPhone в браузерах Safari и Chrome (и иногда на компьютерах в некоторых браузерах) некоторые блоки дергаются и изменяется их размер при анимации. С чем это может быть связано и возможно ли это исправить?

Comment: используйте animation-fill-mode, мне помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По идеи, если анимацию немного ускорить, то подергивание должно пропасть. Связано с тем, что браузеры имеют всё ещё некоторые ограничения для рендеринга CSS3 анимации.

Что бы этого избежать, предлагаю использовать Canvas, который позволяет добиться такой же плавности как и на flash.

В сети так же мелькают советы, как убрать подергивания и мерцания. Но их нужно все проверять. Поэтому можно погуглить на тему: css3 animation, very jerky

Answer (score 1):

Сложно дать какой-либо конкретный совет, ведь файлы, о которых вы говорите, минифицированы и в них практически ничего не понятно.

В каких конкретно браузерах на компьютере происходят баги (нужны название и версии)?

Chrome и Safari являются WebKit браузерами, следует проверить свои анимации на совместимость с WebKit. Например, если есть `transition` в стилях, то, для поддержки всех основных браузеров необходимо следующее:

```
#myelem {
 -webkit-transition: top 1s ease-out 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: top 1s ease-out 0.5s;
 -o-transition: top 1s ease-out 0.5s;
 transition: top 1s ease-out 0.5s;
}
```

Это все, что я могу посоветовать, основываясь на данной информации.

Answer (score 0):

У самого такая же проблема, но она только в Safari и только на планшетах и телефонах IOS. Немного сгладить подёргивание получилось через:

```css
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Но сказать что я получил тот результат, который хотел бы, не могу. Может для вас эффект будет более значительней. Удачи.